# How to know the messages of the UI dispatcher queue in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

The UI dispatcher in my application goes very busy sometimes, because of the invokes and begin-invokes on it, how to know the items on the dispatcher of my UI? are there any tools or vs plugins, or any thing can help me to debug?

Comment: Try to check the events of the [Hooks property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.hooks.aspx) of your dispatcher:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherhooks.aspx